# Why am I getting black spacers after text in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, debugging

So, I followed this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ for inserting text on an image. The code is shown below:

```css
.image{
  position: relative;

}

h2{
  position:absolute;
  top: 200px; 
  left: 200px; 
  width: 100%; 
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}

h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
    
    $("h2")
        .wrapInner("<span>")

    $("h2 br")
        .before("<span class='spacer'>")
        .after("<span class='spacer'>");

});
});
</script>

<div class = "image" id = "news">
  
<h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
```

But when I run the code I have these black things at the end of the first line and starting of the second line as a result of adding the spacing. I think its because of padding twice somehow.

These are not there in the tutorial on the website. Why do I have these and how can I remove them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also write 'transparent' like this:

```
h2 span.spacer {
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your CSS:

```
h2 span.spacer {
    padding: 0 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Seems like your background-colors are overlapping.

Comment: why are they overlapping?

Comment: You have a colored background with transparence and place a spacer with also transparent background-color. These two colors get combined to one color.

Comment: what if i have an image at the back of the text? it still doesn't work. do the background and spacing still get combined?

Answer (score 0):

You should have transparent background for spacer btw:

```
h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
   background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: why did they not do this in the link I provided? and why does their work properly but not mine?

Comment: Because the span inside h2 has color already, which is rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) or 70% opacity of black. So the span spacer double it.

Answer (score 0):

Just make them invisible:

```
.spacer {
    opacity: 0;
}
```